# Is Om the first sound?

Tags: vedas, om

Where does it say that Om is the primordial sound or the first sound? Which verse of the vedas?

Comment: Om is the Pranava given to Sanyassis by Guru to become same as Brahman. "The Pranava is the how, the Atman is the arrow and the Brahman is said to be its mark. It should he hit by one who is self-collected and that which hits becomes, like the arrow, one with the mark, i.e.. Brahman." - Mundaka-upanishad 2.2.3 "The goal which all the Vêdâs uniformly extol, which all acts of tapas speak of, and wishing for which men lead the life of a Brahmachârin, that goal I tell you briefly—It is this—Om."- Katha Upanishad 1.2.15

Comment: Maitrayana Upanishad, See Valkhilya, King conversations